# Is it possible to beautify the output of :to_json (in Crystal's standard lib)?

Tags: json, crystal-lang

I'm using Crystal's JSON module to update `package.json` files and all the output is on one line. Is it possible to control the output of :to_json?

```
require "JSON"
data = File.read("package.json")
data.as_h["version"] = "X.X.X"
puts data.to_json
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `.to_pretty_json()` method. You can pass it an optional indent string: `.to_pretty_json("  ")`

It doesn't seem to be [well-documented](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/object#to_pretty_json%28indent%3AString%3D%26quot%3B%26quot%3B%29-instance-method). But, here's the source: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/json/to_json.cr

Answer (score 2):

`Object#to_pretty_json` should get you far enough. If you need more customization, you could also call `to_json(json : JSON::Builder)` and implement a custom [`JSON::Builder`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/JSON/Builder.html).